Why is the public post function undefined
So I am learning PHP's Laravel and working on a blog post like tutorial, I am trying to store all posts for an authenticated user in a $post variable based on the relationship and I am chaining the methods. But I keep getting Call to a member function posts() on null even though its defined in the User model am I missing something?
//web.php

<?php

use App\Models\Post;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\PostController;
use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;

Route::get('/', function () {
    // $posts = Post::all();
    // $posts = Post::where("user_id", auth("web")->id())->get();
    $posts = auth("web")->user()->posts()->get(); // Error: Call to a member function posts() on null
    return view('home', ["posts" => $posts]);
});

//User.php

<?php

namespace App\Models;

// use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use App\Models\Post;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;

    // ...

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class, "user_id");
    }
}

Here is the full error page for better understanding


Copy/paste the full/exact error text, rather than a paraphrased summary.

I have added an image of the error to better understand the issue @Sammitch

it looks to me like user is undefined here, and your issue lies in your auth() not returning anything. As the error states, it is trying to call posts on null, so you didn't get a user to begin with. Nothing to do with the User model

@JayJay, The way you have defined your route, it only allow the authenticated user to fetch it's related posts.Since the user coming to this route / is not authenticated you are getting this error. I will suggest you to protect the route with auth middleware, only then you will able to fetch it's related posts.

Please note that null and undefined have very specific meanings in PHP, you cannot use them interchangeably. As a general rule, never ever rephrase error messages when looking for help, esp. those you still don't understand.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Error Call to a member function posts() on null states that auth("web")->user() is null and posts() function is being called on null. Laravel's auth("web")->user() returns the user who has logged in. So in this case the function posts() is trying to get posts of the user who doesn't exists.
Just login with a user in your system and code will work.
Also I would like to suggest to use something to validate if user is logged in for example, if(auth()->user())
Even better if you use middleware in your route like this
Route::get('your\route',[YourController::class,'yourFunction'])->middleware(['auth'])
Lastly using compact() when you send data to your view will make your life easier.
return view('home', compact('posts'));
